# stream has already been operated upon or closed - supplier not helping

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java 8 stream coding.
Here is the piece of code, I'm trying to run.

```
Supplier filteredSupplier = () -> Stream.of(filteredStream.toArray(Obj[]::new));
Stream.concat((Stream<Obj>)filteredSupplier.get(), Stream.of(objs)).forEach(some operation);
```

As far as I know, If you use a supplier you can use a stream any times you want by using the get() func on supplier. Still I'm getting the "**stream has already been operated upon or closed**".

Please help me understand, is there any restriction on using a stream coming through supplier as well??

Answer (score 5):

In this line

```
Supplier filteredSupplier = () -> Stream.of(filteredStream.toArray(Obj[]::new));
```

there are two streams: `filteredStream` and the one returned by `Stream.of(...)`.

Each call to the `get` method of your `Supplier` will result in a call to `Stream.of(...)` and hence a new stream being created.  However, each call will use the same `filteredStream`. Your `Supplier` will not work the second time you call it because the `filteredStream` stream was 'used up' during the first call.

To avoid the exception, try replacing the line above with something like the following:

```
    Obj[] array = filteredStream.toArray(Obj[]::new);
    Supplier<Stream<Obj>> filteredSupplier = () -> Stream.of(array);
```

This uses `filteredStream` only once, no matter how many times you call the `Supplier`'s `get` method.

Comment: Thanks for the description. I have a use case, where in I have a stream which I have to use multiple times (filteredStream).. Hence I first convert it to an array to get the supplier for it and then use the supplier to get the stream again and again.  I dont have a source list or collection for a Stream.. How do I work in this case???

Comment: Any inputs anyone?

Comment: @Ka123: in that case you want to create an array from `filteredStream`  once and then create a stream from the array any number of times.  To do that, take the array creation out of the supplier.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Actually, the supplier is completely obsolete as it doesn’t contribute anything to the program logic. When you replace every occurrence of `filteredSupplier.get()` with `Stream.of(array)`, you can remove the entire declaration `Supplier<Stream<Obj>> filteredSupplier = () -> Stream.of(array);` and the program still works as before. The same applies to the question’s code, which is the reason why the supplier didn’t help there, it didn’t change the logic. It’s all about, when and how often `filteredStream.toArray` is invoked. The supplier only obfuscated that.